# How to save the position of a portlet on the portal page?

Tags: java, position, portlet, portal, websphere-portal

I'm trying to build a book shop with three portlets on one portal page. It should look like this:

[image: Before restart]

But if i restart the web-app it looks like this:

[image: After restart]

What do i have to do to save the postion of the portlets in the layout? The layout of the site is still the same, but the portlets aren't on thier positions.

I'm using **Websphere Portal 8.5.5** with the **RAD 9.5**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so if you are using Rad 9.5 I am assuming you are deploying your login portlets each time, in doing so rad removes them from the page and then deploys them agian when you make changes
you way to keep their position would be to either deploy and update them by hand or use xmlaccess to update the page each time